# interface of the list in c++

Tags: c++

I found some interface for the list:
and there I found this constructor

```
template<typenameT>
...

list(size_tnum, constT& val = T());
...
```

can somebody explain what is this:  `constT& val = T()`

thanks in advance

Comment: Some whitespace is required between the type `size_t` and the parameter `num`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const T& val = T()`

This describes a parameter that is taken by const reference, but is optional because the parameter is declared with an initialier. If not supplied then a value initialized temporary (`T()`) is used.

The `list` constructor you've found initializes a `list` with `num` copies of the `val` parameter.